# How to read files from Desktop in Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api application. When I run the application, I perform operations by reading the file on the desktop. It works smoothly. I am converting my application to a windows service. However, when Windows is a service, it cannot read the file on the desktop.

What I implemented when converting the API to a windows service is as follows.

```
sc create ServiceName binPath="ApplicationPath/ApplicationName.exe"
sc start ServiceName
```

My desktop file reading code is as follows.

```
    private static InstalllationModel GetInstalllation()
{
    InstalllationModel installlation = new InstalllationModel();
    string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string configurePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Installation.txt");

    if (File.Exists(configurePath))
    {
        installlation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstalllationModel>(File.ReadAllText(configurePath));
    }


    return installlation;
}
```

HostBuilder Code :

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseWindowsService(options => options.ServiceName = ".NET Server Service")
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

I'm not sure if it's related to permissions in Windows. I would be happy if you help. Thanks.

Comment: " it cannot read the file on the desktop" is an error thrown ? or does the object `installation`  not have the values you expected as is in file?

Comment: There is an HTTP get request. This returns the values read in the file. The GET request returns a response but does not contain any read values.

Comment: I also set a timer Interval with the read value. Since the timer interval value is null because it cannot read the value, I get an error in the relevant class.

Comment: I'm sure it's a file reading problem. Because when I define and write the file content as a string variable in the application, it works smoothly in the service.

Comment: You changed from "Webapplicationbuilder" to "Ihostbuilder" right?

Comment: @Ozgur  Is the service running under the same account role as the web Api application or a role with permission rights to  access the file?

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k service application installed directly in the admin user. I manually gave permission to interact with the desktop in the properties field from the services, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @QiangFu Unfortunately I didn't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the problem.
There is exception when I use both async Action and `GetAsync`.But when I tested with `GetAsync` without using async Action. The call works normally.
Besides, I used this method to create service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-service.

Comment: First of all, please excuse me for replying late. I will only be able to look at the project tomorrow. As far as I understand, rather than the problem in the project, I need to install the service with the necessary permissions when installing the service on Windows. Is it true?

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz I tried without the permission steps in this doc, then the service not work. So I think it's necessary for this method.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by method.

Comment: @OzgurSaklanmaz oh I mean the method of using powershell to create a service. Since you did `sc create` and could open the webpage, maybe you needn't configure permission with that. way

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I'll check it quickly tomorrow and let you know.